# Creating a simple event system

Tags: c++, event-handling

I am trying to make a very simple event system for learning purposes, after seeing some much more complicated code  on the internet I was wondering if what I am doing is fine of if it has major issues. The code works but I am not sure if it is fast and safe.

The part that worries me is that in my test Listener class (KeyListener) I have to do a cast in order to get the correct Event, is this considered bad practice?

Thanks for your help!

Here is the code:

Event.h

```
      extern unsigned int NULL_EVENT;

      extern unsigned int KEY_PRESSED_EVENT;

      extern unsigned int EVENT_AMOUNT;

      class Event
      {
      public:
        Event();
        Event(const Event&);
        Event& operator=(const Event&);

        virtual unsigned int getType() const;
      };
```

Listener.h:

```
      class Listener
      {
      public:
        Listener();
        Listener(const Listener&);
        Listener& operator=(const Listener&);

        virtual unsigned int getEventType() const;
        virtual void onEvent(Event*);
      };
```

EventHandler.h:

```
      class EventHandler
      {
      private:
        LinkedList<Listener*>* listeners;

        void deleteData();
      public:
        EventHandler();
        EventHandler(const EventHandler&);
        EventHandler& operator=(const EventHandler&);
        ~EventHandler();

        void registerListener(Listener*);
        void onEvent(Event&);
      };
```

EventHandler.cpp:

```
EventHandler::EventHandler()
      {
        listeners = new LinkedList<Listener*>[EVENT_AMOUNT];
      }

      EventHandler::EventHandler(const EventHandler& handler)
      {
        listeners = new LinkedList<Listener*>[EVENT_AMOUNT];
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<EVENT_AMOUNT;i++)
        {
          *(listeners + i) = *(handler.listeners + i);
        }
      }

      EventHandler& EventHandler::operator=(const EventHandler& handler)
      {
        deleteData();
        listeners = new LinkedList<Listener*>[EVENT_AMOUNT];
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<EVENT_AMOUNT;i++)
        {
          *(listeners + i) = *(handler.listeners + i);
        }
        return *this;
      }

      EventHandler::~EventHandler()
      {
        deleteData();
      }

      void EventHandler::deleteData()
      {
        delete[] listeners;
      }

      void EventHandler::registerListener(Listener* listener)
      {
        unsigned int id = listener->getEventType();
        assert(id < EVENT_AMOUNT && "Event type is out of bounds!");
        if(!(listeners + id)->contains(listener))
        {
          std::cout << "registering listener of id: " << id << std::endl;
          (listeners + id)->add(listener);
        }
      }

      void EventHandler::onEvent(Event& event)
      {
        unsigned int id = event.getType();
        assert(id < EVENT_AMOUNT && "Event type is out of bounds!");
        LinkedListIterator<Listener*> itt = (listeners + id)->getIterator();
        for(;itt.isValid();itt.next())
        {
          itt.getElement()->onEvent(&event);
        }
      }
```

Here is test Event and a test Listener:
KeyPressedEvent.h:

```
class KeyPressedEvent : public Event
{
protected:
  unsigned int keyCode;

public:
  KeyPressedEvent(unsigned int);
  KeyPressedEvent(const KeyPressedEvent&);
  KeyPressedEvent& operator=(const KeyPressedEvent&);

  unsigned int getKeyCode() const;

  virtual unsigned int getType() const override;
};
```

KeyPressedEvent.cpp

```
KeyPressedEvent::KeyPressedEvent(unsigned int keyCode)
        {
          this->keyCode = keyCode;
        }

        KeyPressedEvent::KeyPressedEvent(const KeyPressedEvent& event)
        {
          keyCode = event.keyCode;
        }

        KeyPressedEvent& KeyPressedEvent::operator=(const KeyPressedEvent& event)
        {
          keyCode = event.keyCode;
          return *this;
        }

        unsigned int KeyPressedEvent::getKeyCode() const
        {
          return keyCode;
        }

        unsigned int KeyPressedEvent::getType() const
        {
          return KEY_PRESSED_EVENT;
        }
```

KeyListener.h:

```
class KeyListener : public Listener
{
public:
  KeyListener();

  virtual unsigned int getEventType() const override;
  virtual void onEvent(Event*) override;
};
```

KeyListener.cpp:

```
KeyListener::KeyListener()
{

}

unsigned int KeyListener::getEventType() const
{
  return KEY_PRESSED_EVENT;
}

void KeyListener::onEvent(Event* e)
{
  KeyPressedEvent* event = (KeyPressedEvent*)e; //Even though I am sure that this is the correct event type, can I do things like this or is this considered bad practice?
  std::cout << "key pressed: " << event->getKeyCode() << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
EventHandler handler;
  KeyListener listener;

  handler.registerListener(&listener);

  KeyPressedEvent event(5);
  handler.onEvent(event);
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. The indentation of the code presented looks inconsistent; two pieces of advice: 1) use blanks, only 2) bracket each code block with lines containing just `~~~` (and possibly a language hint) instead of prefixing each line with another 4 blanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to make a very simple event system for learning purposes,

You've actually made a **very** complex event system.

First, let's explore the requirements of an "event system". I am basing these off a rough examination of your code.

- Custom `Event`s can be defined
- `Handler`s register `Listener`s
- Calls to `Handler::onEvent` get dispatched to all registered `Listener`s

A system which satisfies these requirements could be implemented with a `std::vector` of `std::function`s. Instead of a `Listener` class, it would just be a field or perhaps a type alias. The event structure could be specified in the `std::function<>` type.

Let's use this concept as a reference.

---

**Event.h**

You are declaring every event type in this header essentially as a global variable. This means:

- Code can change the event values at runtime
- You need to modify at least two different files just to declare a new event type
- Events values may be important. Are two different types an alias of each other or not? You won't know until runtime.
- Every new event type created will trigger a rebuild of every dependency of Event.h
- Different runtime modules may disagree on the values of the event types due to this linkage

The event class serves only to create a common base class for other event types. However, I don't see any utility for this. In the straw example I described, handlers must be coupled to their event types to some degree, but not to any base class. **The implementation here requires every client of the system to be coupled to every other client.**

Prefer to use enums, and declare them as privately as possible.

---

`LinkedList` appears to be a learning-exercise utility. As a general rule, prefer `std::vector` when storing a collection of objects. They're very fast and canonically ubiquitous. Note that the algorithmic complexity of adding or removing from the collection is **not** a good reason by itself to use a linked list over a `std::vector`. In this case, the collection stores pointers which are very small, so there's a lot of overhead in each linked list node. Also, every time a linked list node is iterated over, it may induce a cache miss due to indirecting, which a `std::vector` is much less likely to do.

---

As a learning exercise, I recommend trying to trim away at your code until it is at the bare bones of functionality. Do you really need a default constructor that does nothing? Do you need a copy constructor on a type with no data? These should be questions raised when trying to slim down your system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try to implement what you said, hopefully I will end up with something decent. And when I said that I was making a simple event system I ment that the code was primitive, maybee I should have said basic.

Comment: Basic and primitive is sometimes what you want. A teapot is primitive in that it doesn't have many moving or complex parts, but it's intuitive and performs its job very well.